# Chart.js set time xAxes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to set xAxes in charset.js from 00:00 to 23:59 with an interval of 15 minutes.And set yAxes from 0 to 16

But it shows up to me every hour and not until 23:59 only until 00:00.
Thanks !

my ts :

```
   let options = {
      responsive: false,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {

            displayFormats: {
              'minute': 'HH:mm',
              'hour': 'HH:mm'
            }
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'HH mm',
              bounds: 'ticks',
            }
          }
        }]
      },
    };

    Chart.Bar(ctx, {
    /*  data: data,*/
      options: options,
    });
```

data is not set yet.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try with library http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: Im using chart.js liblary